# SharePoint 2019 WFE

Tags: sharepoint

Built a SharePoint 2019 Farm with 4 App Server + 4 WFE.  Main App server runs the Central Admin.  On Creating a new WebApplication/Root Site collection, it is accessible in the main app server running in Central Admin.  In the WFEs getting 404 error when using http://WFESERVERNAME:PORT.  No IIS Logs, seems as if not even hitting IIS.  ANy clue?  Site works when calling using http://APPServer:PORT.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am checking to see if you have solved this issue. If you have any concerns, please feel free to reply.

Answer (score 0):

Is "http://APPServer:PORT" a normal site collection of a web application or the Central Administration?

If it is the Central Administration, it is normal as Central Administration is hosted on App server by default. If you want it running on WFE server, you need to start **Central Administration** service on this WFE server.
[image]

For web applications, its related service is **Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application** service. So, if you want to run site collections of web applications on WFE, need to make sure the following service is running.
[image]